# Условия else выдает ошибку javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код внутри функции:

```
var parent = $(this).parent()
var itemed = tippy(parent[0])
itemed.setProps({
  trigger: 'click',
})
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
  itemed.setContent('Добавлено в сравнение')
} else {
  itemed.setContent('Удалено из сравнения') 
}
```

Условия `if` выполняется
А вот когда доходит до `else` такая ошибка

> Cannot read property 'setProps' of undefined

Comment: написана же ошибка: `itemed === undefined`, что такое `tippy`?

Comment: _Условия if выполняется_ судя по ошибке, условие не выполняется, так как ошибка раньше происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var itemed = tippy(parent[0])
>
> itemed.setProps({   trigger: 'click', })

замените на

```
tippy(parent, { trigger: 'click', })
```